# How to delete old documents from lucene index (filter by Date parameter)

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, documents

I am new to lucene (i'm using JAVA) and i've tried to read all the existing answers in order to find out a solution to my problem. Unfortunately I didn't fix my problem, so I try to ask you again this question:

I have a Date parameter. I need to delete all the documents inside a lucene index that are older than that Date parameter. How can I do it? I've found one solution with the method isDeleted but, unfortunately, is currently deprecated. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the documents matching any query with the [`IndexWriter.DeleteDocuments`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments(org.apache.lucene.search.Query...)) method, such as:

```
String dateString = DateTools.dateToString(myCutoffDate, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
Query dateQuery = TermRangeQuery.newStringRange("dateField", null, dateString, false, false);
myIndexWriter.DeleteDocuments(dateQuery);
```